# Android Loaders don't call onLoadFinished

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have a problem with the use of AsyncTaskLoaders inside of fragments managed by a ViewPager.
The configuration is like this:

Fragment#1 - Loader that loads a picture from disk
Fragment#2 - Loader that loads custom object from disk
Fragment#3 - Loader that loads JSON object from network
Fragment#4 - As the #3

If I omit the Loader in the Fragment#1 it's all ok and as expected.
But if I try to use the Loader in Fragment#1 all the others Loaders don't call the onLoadFinished callback specified in each fragment. I put a bit of Log and I see that all the other loaders properly handle the loadInBackground() method but they are in the reset status after that.

Maybe is there a maximum number of loaders concurrently available or is there a problem with the size of the bitmap loaded?

Each fragment requires to init loader in the *onCreateView()* callback as this

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(STATS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

and implements the  *LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks*  as this

```
@Override
public Loader<UserStats> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    ProfileStatsLoader loader = new ProfileStatsLoader(getActivity(), userId);
    loader.forceLoad();
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<UserStats> loader, UserStats stats) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
    postLoadUI((ProfileStatsLoader) loader, stats);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<UserStats> arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
}
```

The first Loader (that likely is the cause of the failure of the remaining three) code is

```
public class ProfilePictureLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Bitmap> {

private static final String TAG = ProfilePictureLoader.class.getCanonicalName();
private User user;
private int maxSize;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Throwable error;

public ProfilePictureLoader(Context context, User user, int maxSize) {
    super(context);
    this.user = user;
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

public Throwable getError() {
    return error;
}

public Bitmap getPicture() {
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
public Bitmap loadInBackground() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading bitmap for user " + user.getUuid());
    Log.w(TAG, "Is reset at start? " + this.isReset());

    ImageUtils iu = new ImageUtils(getContext());
    String localProfilePicturePath = iu.loadBitmapURIForUser(user.getUuid());

    // if the user has not a picture saved locally (for logged user) neither
    // have never set a profile picture (for online users), return a null
    // bitmap
    if (localProfilePicturePath == null && !user.hasProfilePicture())
        return null;

    try {
        if (user.isStoredLocally()) {
            // load local profile image
            bitmap = null;
            if (localProfilePicturePath != null)
                // load profilePictureMaxSize px width/height
                bitmap = ImageUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(localProfilePicturePath, maxSize, maxSize);
        } else {
            // download remotely
            bitmap = UserRESTClient.downloadUserPicture(user.getUuid(), UserRESTClient.PICTURE_MEDIUM_SIZE);
        }
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading bitmap for user " + user.getUuid() + ": " + t);
        t.printStackTrace();

        error = t;
        return null;
    }finally{
        Log.w(TAG, "Is reset? " + this.isReset());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: There is a lot of code but it is redundant, so I have just edited to include only the code I think is relevant. But if you think more code is necessary I try to write it here without make the question hard to understand.

Comment: if there is a lot of code, you need to narrow it donw first

Comment: The code in the Loaders and the Fragments is quite similar, so I wrote here only the relevant parts of Loaders initialization and callbacks. The Loaders I have written simply override the loadInBackground() method to load the required data (and I have verified that the data load properly).

Comment: (there is probably something in your first loader, btw, why don't you put the code from this one here ?)

Comment: the postLoadUI() is a simply method to adapt UI according to the data retrieved by the loader (hide some views and make visible some others). I edit the question to include the code of the first loader as you require :-)

Comment: did you ever solve your problem? I have the same question. if you did, could you help me too.

Comment: @dariusiv start by following [Implementing Loaders (part 3)](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html).

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this issue, not sure if this is relevant to your case, but if your loaders are all using the same id (first param passed to the restartLoader or initLoader methods) they will restart and stomp all over each other while paging if one takes longer than another. Hope this can still be relevant to someone that run into this!